# CORS header issue evolved to a "Refused to set unsafe header" using a GET method without access to the backend

Tags: angular

I'm trying to receive RSS feed from Bing.

For instance - this URL: https://www.bing.com/news/search?q=cool+thing&go=Search&qs=n&form=QBNT&pq=lottery+tips&sc=7-11&sp=-1&sk=&FORM=HDRSC6&format=RSS

I keep getting two errors: 
"Refused to set unsfae header" 
"blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"

I've tried using https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ to help me with the header and got "Missing required request header. Must specify one of: origin,x-requested-with". I tried to set the missing header manually.

Here is the API service:

```
export class ApiService {

   headerDict = {

    // 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    // 'Accept': 'application/json',
    // 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
    'origin': 'null'
  }

   requestOptions = {   

    headers: new HttpHeaders(this.headerDict), 
  };

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getNews() {

    return this.http.get(environment.requestURL, this.requestOptions);
  }
```

In the call for the service I just try to console.log the result

```
  ngOnInit() {

    this.api.getNews().subscribe((ret) => {

      console.log(ret);
    });
  }
```

After trying like this I got "Refused to set unsafe header "origin""

PS - I've tried to use Origin, adding cross-anywhere and rapid API is not relevant for now

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` is a **response** header, so setting it in your **request** doesn't make any sense. It's something Bing would have to set, and obviously they're not going to set it, for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue arise from the fact you need to add a key to the header.
It is stated in the documentation:

> Every request to the Bing Web Search API must include a header that
>   contains the Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key, which is your private access
>   key. Access Keys are available for exploring these APIs.

So you'd might want to set your request params like this:

```
const httpOptions = {
        headers: {
            'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscriptionKey,
        }
    };
```

You can get your Bing API key here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/try/cognitive-services/?api=bing-web-search-api